# check if $X,Y$ are independent

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have to solve the following exercise:

I have given two absolut continous random variables with probability density $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi} \mathbb{1}_K(x,y)$ and K is defined as $K:=  \bigl\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2≤ 1\bigr\}  $ and $\mathbb{1}_K$  as $\mathbb{1}_K := \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \in K\\
0& \text{if } x \not\in K    \\ 
\end{cases}$

Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

I want to show the result by the 1 dimensional probability densities and look whether their product is f(x,y).

But how can I compute the 1 dimensional probability densities?

Comment: $f(x,y)$ is simply $\frac{1}{\pi}$ when $(x,y)\in K$. Can you find the marginal densities now? Do you know how to find marginals from joint density?

Comment: Another way you can tackle the question of independence is more conceptual. If you know that $X=0$, what does that tell you about the probability that $Y \in [.5, 1]$? What about the case where $X=1$?

Comment: Hint: Compute $P(X>.8,Y>.8)$, $P(X>.8)$ and $P(Y>.8)$. To compute marginals, recall that, fr example, $$f_X(x)=\int_\mathbb Rf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$$

Comment: my approach was to calculate it like this 

$$F_{X}(t)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}H(X≤t,Y≤n)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{(-\infty,t]\times(-\infty,n]}\frac{1}{\pi} \mathbb{1}_{K}(x,y) \; d(x,y)= \int_{(- \infty, t]} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{\pi} \mathbb{1}_{K}(x,y) \; dy \; dx$$ 


But i don't know how to calculate the integral